# On the meaning of the verb "give" in the phrase "give family histories of something"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Consider the sentence below.

> They often attributed their alcoholism to connubial stress, boredom, or depression. A large percentage of the women **give family histories of** alcoholism.

([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=QtJoCwAAQBAJ&pg=RA5-PR89&dq=often+attributed+their+alcoholism+to+connubial+stress,+boredom,+or+depression&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ2fvK49zMAhVCSSYKHWB5AWUQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=often%20attributed%20their%20alcoholism%20to%20connubial%20stress%2C%20boredom%2C%20or%20depression&f=false))

I can guess that it implies large percentage of the women afflicted with alcoholism have had a alcoholic person in their family.

I scrutinized the verb "give" in my Oxford dictionary, but I was not able to come across with any definition related to the above context.

Could you please tell me, which definition of the verb "give" has been used in the above sentence?

---

More Info:

I have checked below definitions, but I'm not able to discern the appropriate definition used above.

> 1. provide someone with something
> 2. make someone owner of something
> 3. put medicine in someone
> 4. cause effect/experience
> 5. communicate
> 6. perform action
> 7. allow someone to do something
> 8. pass illness to someone else
> 9. pay money
> 10. stretch/bend/break etc
> 11. change decision
> 12. use all time/energy

Comment: Thank you for your hard work trying to discover the best meaning. Do you have the source of this quote, such as the name of the text, book, journal,   magazine...? And a link to it, perhaps?

Comment: Okay, I've added a matching source. Note that the text says *family histories* (plural), as *family history* without a determiner (such as the indefinite article) is incorrect.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Thank you for the correction. I wasn't online for hours. However, you are absolutely right about the article and I am sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A large percentage of the women **give**  family histories  of alcoholism.

Words like *give* have such a broad usage that it can be difficult to pin down. In your example it is related to providing information.
I would use one of these for [give](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/give):

> 4) to relay; pass along"   ⇒ *to give regards to someone*"
>   14) to put forward for acceptance or rejection; offer; proffer"   ⇒ *to give a suggestion*"

In your definitions, 5) communicate is the closest one.

Answer (score 1):

> They often attributed their alcoholism to connubial stress, boredom, or depression. A large percentage of the women **give family histories of** alcoholism.

*Give* here most likely refers to when a woman *reports* her family history to a medical professional or social worker.

Frankly, *give* is not very idiomatic in this sentence and the verb *report* is what I would use. But I understand the book  is trying to use simple words.

So *give* here means *report* 
; (*communicate* is close to this).

Note that in *reporting* her family history  she is *"giving it" to somebody* (using words),    so this falls under the general idea of  Definition 1.

Your  guess about the clause is correct  as a "family history"  is

> The part of a medical history concerned with diseases, traits, and causes of death occurring within a patient's family.

([Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/family-history?q=family+history+))